# Intermediate Value Property and Discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac {1}{x^2}\right)$ defined as $f(0)=1$  satisfies the intermediate value property on $\mathbb R$.

I am confused as to what this question is asking. Is it saying that for any closed interval in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ that the function is continuous since $\frac {1}{x^2}$ is continuous on that interval?

Comment: The function is continuous in any interval $[a,b]$ where $a$ are both positive or both negative. But the function is not continuous at $0$. However, it still has the intermediate value property.

Comment: You know the intermediate value theorem holds on (-inf,0) and (0,inf) because it's continuous.  Show it is true on any interval [a,b] a <0 b>0.  That is, for any real number,v,between f(a) and f (b) the is a c between a and be such that f (c) =v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that $f(x)$ satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem.  That is, for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $y$ which is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is some $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(c)=y$.  It is *not* saying anything about $f$ being continuous anywhere.

(Here "between" can mean either strict inequalities or non-strict inequalities, as long as it means the same thing both times; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371989/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-between) for more discussion of this.)